# openssl RAND_load_file always returns 0

Tags: c, ssl, random, openssl, entropy

I'm trying to read from `/dev/random/` on linux using.

```
int bytes = RAND_load_file("/dev/random", 16);
printf("%d bytes read", bytes);
```

This always outputs 0 bytes read.

`/dev/random` is being fed by a software entropy source. I made sure `/dev/random` does have enough data. According to docs `RAND_load_file` should return no. of bytes read but this is not happening.

Comment: Your code is correct, the problem is apparently in reading the `/dev/random/`. If there would not be enough data, the program would just wait. You may try checking some permissions, though I didn't have to do anything to make it work.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what OS? Is it Debian? As far as I know, Debian is the only modern desktop/server OS that does not have a modern entropy gatherer, and it suffers depletion in 2015

Comment: It's RHEL 6. I tried to cat /dev/random and it's lively.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> *I'm trying to read from /dev/random/ on linux using...*
>
> *This always outputs 0 bytes read.*

According to the `urandom(4)` man pages:

> The character special files /dev/random and /dev/urandom (present
>   since Linux 1.3.30) provide an interface to the kernel's random number
>   generator.
>
> When read, the /dev/random device will only return random bytes 
>   within the estimated number of bits of noise in the entropy pool. 
>   /dev/random should be suitable for uses that need very high quality
>   randomness such as  one-time  pad  or  key generation.  When the
>   entropy pool is empty, reads from /dev/random will block until
>   additional environmental  noise is gathered.

Some OSes block, like OpenBSD. Other OSes don't block, like Debian and Ubuntu. For those that don't block on a short read, they return the number of bytes actually returned (which may be less than requested). So your first problem could be entropy depletion. You should check `errno` to get additional information.

I've also seen problems where integer math is used when estimating entropy during the addition of entropy to the device. The problem flows through the system and shows its head when you try to random numbers from the device. Something like:

```
int bytes = 128;
int estimate = bytes / 256;
```

The problem is you need a `float`, not an `int`. Otherwise, your estimate of entropy is 0.

```
int bytes = 128;
float estimate = (float)bytes / 256;
```

---

> /dev/random is being fed by a software entropy source. I made sure /dev/random does have enough data.

That's somewhat of a red flag to me... One thing you *should not* be doing is discussed on LWN.net: [Don't play dice with random numbers](https://lwn.net/Articles/525459/). Don't link `dev/random` to `/dev/urandom`. You should probably wander over to [Information Security Stack Exchange](https://security.stackexchange.com/) and discuss your needs and methods.

There's lots of good reading returned from [linux random number generator site:lwn.net](http://www.google.com/search?q=linux+random+number+generator+site%3Alwn.net&oq=linux+random+number+generator+site%3Alwn.net). I see the patches for mobile OSes is discussed, which might help you with your bigger engineering problem.

---

Also, here's from the same man page:

> If  your  system  does  not  have  /dev/random and /dev/urandom
>   created already, they can be created with the following commands:
>
> ```
> mknod -m 644 /dev/random c 1 8
> mknod -m 644 /dev/urandom c 1 9
> chown root:root /dev/random /dev/urandom
> ```
>
> When a Linux system starts up without much  operator  interaction, 
>   the entropy  pool  may  be in a fairly predictable state.  This
>   reduces the actual amount of noise in the entropy  pool  below  the 
>   estimate. In order  to counteract this effect, it helps to carry
>   entropy pool information across shut-downs and start-ups.  To do this,
>   add the  following lines  to  an  appropriate  script which is run
>   during the Linux system start-up sequence:
>
> ```
> echo "Initializing random number generator..."
> random_seed=/var/run/random-seed
> # Carry a random seed from start-up to start-up
> # Load and then save the whole entropy pool
> if [ -f $random_seed ]; then
>     cat $random_seed >/dev/urandom
> else
>     touch $random_seed
> fi
> chmod 600 $random_seed
> poolfile=/proc/sys/kernel/random/poolsize
> [ -r $poolfile ] && bytes=`cat $poolfile` || bytes=512
> dd if=/dev/urandom of=$random_seed count=1 bs=$bytes
> ```
>
> Also, add the following lines in an appropriate  script which is run
>   during the Linux system shutdown:
>
> ```
> # Carry a random seed from shut-down to start-up
> # Save the whole entropy pool
> echo "Saving random seed..."
> random_seed=/var/run/random-seed
> touch $random_seed
> chmod 600 $random_seed
> poolfile=/proc/sys/kernel/random/poolsize
> [ -r $poolfile ] && bytes=`cat $poolfile` || bytes=512
> dd if=/dev/urandom of=$random_seed count=1 bs=$bytes
> ```